# How to get current route path in helper in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm creating a helper and I need to access the current route name. I'm using Ember CLI with ES6 and so I don't have access to `App` object.

Here's what I have.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

/**
 * {{route-active 'route' ['stringIfActive' ['stringIfNot']]}}
 */
export function routeActive(params/*, hash*/) {
  var currentRoute = null; // we need this
  if( ! params.length ) {
    return;
  }
  return currentRoute === params[0] ?
    params[1] || 'active' :
    params[2] || '';
}

export default Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper(routeActive);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's a private API, I've been known to use and abuse the container for when I need it. The application controller has the currently active route as a property called `currentPath`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper( function(value, options) {
    var appCtrl = this.container.lookup("controller:application");
    return appCtrl.get('currentPath');
});
```

This assumes you wanted your helper to simply return the value. If you need to return something else, well at least I got you this far I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to go with this if I can't find any alternatives, but as far as I know we shouldn't be using this private API. Is there no other way?

Comment: the other alternative is that every single controller has to `needs: ['application']` and you're bound helper has to take the `currentPath` as a parameter

Comment: That's even worse. I'll keep using your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: the whole "shouldn't use a private API" idea only matters really when versions change. Just a test around this helper and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

With the shift to components, it is harder to get route name.  The best way is to add an initializer such as

```
ember g initializer router
```

(from command line), and

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('route', 'router', 'router:main');
  application.inject('component', 'router', 'router:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'router',
  initialize
};
```

in a initializers/router.js.  You can also inject into controller if you need to.  Then just do simply

```
this.get('router.currentRouteName');
```

in JS, or

```
{{router.currentRouteName}}
```

in template.

This is the only way I have found to get it reliably, and observable in Ember 2.4